# Best place to put phpunit DB test in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony-2.1

I do some unit test in all my doctrine entities in a Symfony2 Project. I test setter/getter in a class UserTest and also setter/getter with db persistance in a class UserDbTest, all the files are in an `Entity` Folder under the test Folder
is it a good think to testing both, and what's the best place to put the Db classes?

Thx for your advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not have custom database logic (which you should not have) in your `Entity` classes you don't have to create unit and functional tests. Doctrine is tested, i.e. it is ensured that `persist`/`flush` work correctly and you do not have to duplicate these tests.

However, if you want to test, for example, if your queries work correctly I personally have a `XYManager` class (where `XY` is the name of the entity), where I put all custom database logic (and further abstraction) in it. My approach was inspired by the FOSUserBundle (see their [UserManager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php)).

In my projects both the `Entity` and the `EntityManger` classes are in the `Entity` folder of the bundle and the tests for these classes are in the `Tests/Entity` folder. Since functional tests take a lot longer than unit tests I separate them using the `@group` annotation of PHPUnit. I add `@group unit` to all tests that do not require a database and are not of `WebTestCase` and `@group functional` to all tests that do require a database or are of `WebTestCase`.

If I want to execute only the unit tests I can do

```
phpunit -c app/ --group unit`
```

and

```
phpunit -c app/ --group functional
```

will only execute the functional tests.

```
phpunit -c app/
```

will execute both functional and unit tests.